# Преобразование формата данных DATE из одного типа в другой в MS SQL, например dd.mm.yyyy в mm.dd.yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Есть ли возможность преобразовать даты вида `dd.mm.yyyy` к виду `mm.dd.yyyy`. Например, есть столбец в таблице с датами за 5 лет, которые имеют вид, к примеру `30.12.2015`,и находится эта таблица в одной БД, а вставить все эти даты из столбца необходимо в другую таблицу(в другой БД) , в которой по умолчанию эта же дата будет в виде `12.30.2015`. Как можно это сделать, не используя `SET LANGUAGE`? Лучшим вариантом было бы именно преобразование `dd.mm.yyyy` в `mm.dd.yyyy`, то есть русский формат к формату по умолчанию (англ, США). Такая необходимость возникает при импорте файла CSV или XML, в котором даты заданы именно в виде `dd.mm.yyyy` и часто сталкиваешься с несовместимостью типов представления дат, соответственно хотелось бы их сразу привести к виду по умолчанию `mm.dd.yyyy`.

Comment: Можно ли это как-то сделать с помощью переменных, "разбив" на части значения дат в столбце?

Answer (score 2):

Ни один из используемых вами форматов даты не гарантирует однозначного перевода текстового представления даты в тип `date` или `datetime`.

Предлагаю при экспорте в csv или xml использовать `ISO` формат `YYYYMMDD`, который на любом SQL Server будет интерпретироваться однозначно независимо от языковых настроек.

Для перевода к текстовому представлению по ISO формату можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией: `convert(varchar, DateColumn, 112)`

Подробнее можно прочесть в [данном разделе документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: То есть после импорта файла сделать соответствующую конвертацию уже в БД?

Comment: Я бы делал в процессе экспорта, если у вас есть возможность контролировать данный процесс. если - нет, после импорта. Причем cast('YYYYMMDD' as date) будет приводиться к дате всегда однозначно

Answer (score 0):

select format(col1,'MM.dd.yyyy')

Comment: Не срабатывает так